# Deploying war file created using jersey api

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am completely new to Java ( Beginner Java Developer). Our previous proj was created using Jersey API. I am trying to understand the project as I was not in the team of that project developers.

My Question is.. I have created the War file to that application and deployed it in tomcat. But whenever I click that project from the list, it returns an error (Requested resource is not available). I want know if I can deploy Jersey API web app in Tomcat or not? Also If I can, What may be reasons for that error? I tried everywhere and looked into all other threads but could not understand anything.

Also there is a   in web.xml of our project. What is the use of this?

Please help me. Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I want know if I can deploy Jersey API web app in Tomcat or not?**

Yes, you can. You should check your version of Tomcat, and which libraries are required to work with Jersey (usually Jersey jar itself and some common utilities). However, I didnt quite understand "was created using Jersey API". Did you use some Jersey-specific code? Because Jersey is just an implementation of some specification (namely JSR-311).

**What may be reasons for that error?**

Path is not specified properly, resource not initialized, etc.

**Also there is a in web.xml of our project. What is the use of this?**

It is a file that is responsible for the settings of 1 application. In your case, your war-archive. In web.xml you can specify the path to your war resources. Nowadays, all resources can be specified with annotations, and no need to modify web.xml exists.

Comment: Got it.. About that Jersey API, I mean we used Jersey Implementation. Also, As I am trying to deploy this war file in tomcat 7, in the message, it is showing as OK. I think, if it is deployed correctly, it must show OK-Deployed... something like this right?? And according to my log files, there are no errors at all. Please correct me if am wrong about that msg OK thing.

Comment: I mean the msg like "OK - Deployed application at context path /foo".

Comment: It means there is some problem with your resources. Yes, if there were errors they would be shown in the log. try looking for your resoures under /foo/...sth... Most probably you cant find your own paths to your resources

Comment: Yes, Thank you. There is 1 file missing. Thanks a lot. I have to create a new thread about converting my war file into .exe. Can you please help me with that?? I will post the link to that thread here.

Comment: Can you please take a look into this too?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566700/converting-war-to-exe-testing-restful-webservice