# Converting War to .exe / Testing Restful Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am a newbie to this Rest Web Services. 
This question is already posted. But I cannot understand a thing. I have two questions here.

1. When we created a WebApp with soap web services, we generated a test client to test it. Is there a way we can test Rest Webservices? (Using Eclipse IDE, Generated test client in the following way.
   File---> new---> other---> web service---> web service client.  So, now how can i test Restful web services? (I found one Rest Client tool, but I dont understand how to use that (Newbie :)  ).
2. I need to find a way to give our war file to client as .exe file. I  didn't understand what exactly that meant, but here is the requirement. 
   "We need to give our client this in the form of .exe file, like whenever we download some .exe file, it will ask us to Run, Accept license, Browse destination, and such things. And also he shouldn't be able to see our code."
   This is what exactly our senior management told me and Is there a way we can make it possible??
   (I showed him the InstallJammer and then he said the client shouldn't see the code.)

Answer (score 0):

For Question 2:
See some packaging tool like [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download) or [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) or [InnoSetup](http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)